# Internet Explorer 9 compatible Jquery Mp3 player?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, mp3

Can you please suggest me a mp3 jplayer link that would work in internet explorer 9 smoothly?i found  one but it didn't work in IE 9 and gives following error message.

Error:-

```
Jplayer 2.1.0:id='jquery_jplayer_1':Error!
Media URL could not be loaded.
Check media URL is valid.
Context:Address of mp3 file that is placed remotely.
```

This is my code:-

```
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadmedia() {
  $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('setMedia', {

      mp3: 'http://lecion.blob.core.windows.net/sixty-vocab-files//UploadSound/7fd752a6-97ef-4a99-b324-a160295b8ac4/43/Kalimba.mp3'
  });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer({
    ready: loadmedia,
    swfPath: 'Jplayer.swf',
    //solution: 'flash,html',
    errorAlerts: true,
    supplied: 'mp3',
   // wmode: 'window'
  });
});
 </script>
   <script src="jquery.jplayer.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the HTML5 audio tag?

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

refer [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp) for more info

Comment: I am newbie and just downloaded above code.Please tell me where to insert audio tag?

Thanks alot

Comment: Place it in the file which corresponds to the view where you would want the player to appear, and provide the link to the mp3 or the audio file that you want to play.

Comment: I placed it inside function loadmedia() and commented existing  mp3 link,but it didn't work.